# Importance sampling: form of weights

Tags: monte-carlo, importance-sampling

My question is motivated by page 8 of http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_defreitas_gordon_smcbookintro.pdf but the jist is the following:

We want to evaluate $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}(f(X))$ where $X\sim \pi$. We may sample from $\nu$ which leads to the following approximation (abusing notation wrt densities)
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\pi}(f(X))=\int f(x) \pi(x)\,dx=\int f(x) w(x)\nu(x)\,dx\approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(Z_{i})w(Z_{i})
$$
with all $Z_{i}\sim \nu$ and $w(x)=\pi(x)/\nu(x)$. This is an unbiased estimtor. My problem is this; in the link I posted the approximation used is
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}_{\pi}(f(X))}{1}=\frac{\int f(x) w(x)\nu(x)\,dx}{\int w(x)\nu(x)\,dx}\approx\frac{n^{-1}\sum f(Z_{i})w(Z_{i})}{n^{-1}\sum w(Z_{i})}
$$
which is "biased as the ratio of two estimators". Why then consider that estimator and not the more basic one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would prefer the first one, but sometimes you can't evaluate those weights at each sample $z_i$: $w(z_i)=\pi(z_i)/\nu(z_i)$.

Sometimes you can only evaluate something proportional to the target density, call it $\gamma(z) = c \pi(z)$ for some unknown constant $c$. Then your un-normalized weight would be $w(z_i)=\gamma(z_i)/\nu(z_i)$. These don't sum to $1$, however, so you would normalize them by dividing by their sum. The normalized weights would be $\tilde{w}(z_i) = w(z_i)/\sum_j w(z_j).$ In this case you are still using the law of the large numbers as a justification. You divide the numerator and denominator by the number of samples, and apply LLN to both terms.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that case before, but the document said $\pi$ was a distribution and I just assumed probability distribution. Thought I was missing something. Thanks for your help.